# php getting part of a URL into a string

Tags: php, regex

Hi guys i m using this code to get the id on my url

```
$string = $url;
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/.*?\/(\d+)\/?/s', $string, $matches);

$id = $matches[1][0];
```

this code works for urls like

```
http://mysite.com/page/1
http://mysite.com/page/somepage/2
http://mysite.com/page/3/?pag=1
```

i will have  id = 1  / id = 2 / id = 3

but for a url like this

```
http://mysite.com/page/122-page-name/1
```

this returns id = 122

THe id i m try to get always will be the last part of the url or will have /?p= after

so the urls type i can have

```
http://mysite.com/page/1
http://mysite.com/page/some-page/2
http://mysite.com/page/12-some-name/3
http://mysite.com/page/some-page/4/?p=1
http://mysite.com/page/13-some-page/5/?p=2
```

id = 1 / id = 2 / id = 3 / id = 4 / id = 5

Answer (score 0):

If your id will always be located at the end of your url, you could `explode` the contents of your url and take the last element of the resulting array. If it may include variables (like `?pag=1`) you can add a validation after the `explode` to check for the variable.

```
$urlArray = explode('/', $url);
$page = end($urlArray);
if(strpos($page, 'pag')!==false){
    //get the contents of the variable from the $page variable
    //exploding the variable through the ? variable and getting
    //the numeric characters at the end
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would favor URL parsing over trying to use a regex, especially if you have a wide variety of (valid) URLs to deal with.

```
end(array_filter(explode('/', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH))));
```

The `array_filter` deals with the trailng slash.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's always at the end or has ?p=x after it you can do the following:

```
$params = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$c = count($params);
if (is_int($params[$c - 1])  
    $id = $params[$c - 1];
else
    $id = $params[$c - 2];
```

Comment: @AlvaroLouzada It shouldn't. It should set `$id = $params[$c -1]` which will be the last one. I'll double check though.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, more of a "how to work this out for yourself" answer :]

Place this code at the top of your page, before anything else (but after `<?php`)

```
foreach($_SERVER as $k => $v) {
    echo $k.' = '.$v.'<br />';
}
exit;
```

Now load up each of the different URIs in a different tab and look at the results. You should be able to work out what you need to do.